# Acumatica - remove generic style vent handler

Tags: acumatica

How to remove a event handler if it is defined with generic event handler syntax..
I am not getting the syntax to remove it like we have with old style of event handler defination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some circumstances you need to remove the event explicitly.
There doesn't seem to be much difference from old events in Acumatica latest version. The method name convention is different and uses underscore character. The event handler needs a public or protected access modifier to be referenced.

```
public class UserProfileMaintExt : PXGraphExtension<MyProfileMaint>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        Base.RowSelected.RemoveHandler<Users>(_);
    }

    protected virtual void _(Events.RowSelected<Users> e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Removing event handler with suggested signature gives compile time error- Cannot convert from method group tp pxrowupdated

Comment: Any details? My answer example is on 'Row Selected' event and your error is on 'Row Updated'.

Answer (score 1):

*Since no version was provided, this was done in 2021 R1*

There isn't much information provided here but from what I believe you're asking, the means to override event handlers is very similar. Take ARInvoiceEntry as an example. There exists an event handler for the RowSelected event of ARAdjust `_(Events.RowSelected<ARAdjust> e)`.

To override this in your graph extension you need the following method declaration:

```
    public virtual void _(Events.RowSelected<ARAdjust> e, PXRowSelected del)
    {
        del?.Invoke(e.Cache, e.Args); //This line calls the core Acumatica code, if you desire to remove the call completely remove this line (or comment it out)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We are getting error -

can not convert from 'method group' to 'pxrowupdated